# Libreoffice has different behaviour in Debian Jessie and Ubuntu

Tags: 16.04, libreoffice, debian, docker

I'm using docker in order to set up the environment needed in order to run a converter (any format to pdf) through LibreOffice. I have a certain file; when I run it in the Jessie environment (base image is Debian Jessie) the conversion is not good (blacked out lines). When the base image is Ubuntu 16.04 the conversion is great.

My question is, what package(s) is Jessie missing (compared to Ubuntu) that would affect the conversion?

```
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y -q install \
    build-essential openjdk-8-jdk maven wget unzip curl \
    fonts-crosextra-carlito fonts-crosextra-caladea \
    fonts-opensymbol hyphen-fr hyphen-de hyphen-en-us hyphen-it hyphen-ru \
    fonts-dejavu fonts-dejavu-core fonts-dejavu-extra \
    fonts-dustin fonts-f500 fonts-fanwood fonts-freefont-ttf fonts-liberation \
    fonts-lmodern fonts-lyx fonts-sil-gentium fonts-texgyre fonts-tlwg-purisa
```

Comment: Debian Jessie is old-stable or version 8. You're comparing it to a much newer Ubuntu 16.04 LTS, where a more appropriate comparison might be Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Are you surprised?  (the current Debian Stable is Stretch or 9, and really you can't compare debian releases with Ubuntu as they rarely match up as Ubuntu is calendar fixed; debian isn't...)

Comment: Hello @guiverc, thanks for your help. No I'm not comparing them, I understand what you are saying. It's just that we are using jessie in production and I had the idea to try and see what ubuntu does, but in the end I have to replicate the behaviour in jessie. I don't care about all the other features differences so I was hoping that it's a matter of some packages missing or needing update.

Comment: I'll try the same with stretch and see if it has the same results as 16.04. Thanks again

Comment: You should compare **stretch** with **xenial**, not **jessie** with **xenial**. 16.04 is based on **stretch**.

Comment: Ok tried it and it works great in 9.3 as well. Sorry for the trouble people. @guiverc if you would like please post your comment as an answer so I can accept

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debian Jessie, or Debian 8 is known as *old-stable*. You are comparing it to a much newer Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. A more appropriate comparison might be Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

The current Debian 'stable' release is Stretch (Debian 9) so it'd make a closer match to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Note however Debian & Ubuntu are unlikely to perfectly match as they are on different release cycles; Ubuntu's releases are date fixed, Debian isn't and on a longer cycle even if its releases occur roughly two years like LTS releases of Ubuntu.

Ubuntu is built largely from debian-testing (currently Debian 10 or Buster), but also contains Debian Sid ....

I'm suggesting comparing Debian 8 with Ubuntu 14.04LTS, or if you want Ubuntu 16.04LTS try Debian 9.   (from comments.. with thanks to @N0rbert who helped too)